# Highlight multiple postal code fusion tables

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to display multiple FSA(Postal code) on a map using fusion tables data.There are more than 2050 records that i want to display in the map highlighted in red color for example.In the current scenario style is only applicable for a limited amount of data and all the FSA are not colored that are reserved.This is my code.Please check it and let me know what wrong I am doing.

```
      var ab1="<?php echo $ab; ?>"; 
      layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
              select: "col5\x3e\x3e0",
    from: "17DPgq8Vt4AmBfLU8T_uhF_-mcJuoAj4Sxij8ZoTq"

            },

   styles: [{
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#0053DC',
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    strokeColor: '#000000', 
    strokeWeight: 0.6
  }}, {
  where: "'CFSAUID' IN('"+ab1+"')",
  polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: '#82090B',
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    strokeColor: '#000000', 
    strokeWeight: 0.6 
  }
  }
  ]

   });
```

All the data are coming in this :

```
 var ab1="<?php echo $ab; ?>";
```

If I print $ab its coming this :

```
                var 'V8S','V0S','V0R','V9L','V8L','V9B','V8Z','V9E','V8M','V8Y','V8X','V9A','V8V','V8R','V8T','V8W','V8P','V8N','V9G','V9X','V9P','V9R','V9T','V9S','V9K','V9Y','V9J','V9H','V0P','V0N','V8A','V9W','V9M','V9N','V9V','V8K','V6T','V7S','V7R','V7N','V7K','V7J','V7H','V7G','V3H','V3E','V3B','V3C','V3K','V3J','V5A','V5B','V7L','V7M','V7P','V6A','V5L','V5K','V5C','V5G','V5M','V5N','V5T','V5Y','V5Z','V6H','V6J','V6K','V6L','V5V','V6R','V6S','V6N','V6M','V5W','V5R','V3N','V5E','V3Y','V4R','V2X','V2W','V4S','V2V','T1S','T2J','T1V','T2W','T2Y','T2X','T3M','T2Z','T3S','T1X','T2C','T3E','T3Z','T3H','T2T','T2S','T2G','T2H','T2V','T2B','T2A','T1Y','T3J','T3N','T2K','T2E','T2R','T3C','T2P','T2M','T2N','T3B','T2L','T3A','T3G','T3L','T3K','T3P','T3R','T4B','T1P','T9E','T6H','T8B','T8C','T8E','T8G','T8L','T8A','T6S','T8H','T6X','T6W','T7Y','T9G','T4X','T6T','T6L','T6J','T6K','T6E','T6R','T6M','T6N','T6B','T6P','T6C','T5W','T6G','T5R','T5T','T5S','T5P','T5N','T5K','T6A','T5H','T5J','T5A','T5Y','T5B','T5G','T5C','T5E','T5M','T5V','T5L','T6V','T8N','T5X','T5Z','T8T','T7X','V2Z','V3S','V4W','V4X','V2T','V2S','V2Y','V1M','V3A','V4N','V4P','V3G','V4A','V4B','V4L','V4K','V4M','V3X','V3W','V4E','V4C','V4G','V6W','V7A','V7E','V7C','V6Y','V6X','V6V','V3M','V3V','V3R','V3T','V5J','V7B','V6P','V5X','V5P','V5S','V3L','V5H','S7K','S7T','S0A','S0E','S0K','S0G','S0C','S0H','S0N','S0L','S4P','S4A','S3N','S9H','S4H','S4L','S4V','S4S','S4W','S4N','S4T','S4X','S4R','S4Y','S4Z','S2V','S6K','S6H','S6J','S0J','S6V','S0P','S0M','S9X','S9A','S7J','S7M','S7V','S7H','S7N','S7W','S7S','S7L','S7P','S9V','R5A','R2N','R3V','R0A','R3Y','R3T','R3X','R2C','R2J','R2M','R3S','R4H','R3P','R3R','R3M','R3L','R3N','R3K','R3J','R2G','R3C','R4A','R2E','R2V','R2P','R2X','R3W','R2K','R2W','R3E','R2Y','R3G','R2H','R2L','R3A','R3B','R3H','R2R','R4J','R4K','R4L','R0H','R0C','R0E','R1A','R0G','R6W','R6M','R5G','R1N','R5H','R0L','R7N','R0J','R0K','R0M','R7A','R0B','R9A','R8A','R8N','N8H','N0R','N9Y','N9V','N0P','N8M','N8N','N8P','N9J','N9A','N9H','N9G','N9E','N9C','N9B','N8W','N8V','N9K','N8T','N8X','N8Y','N8R','N8S','N7M','N7L','N0L','N0N','N8A','N0M','N7G','N5L','N5H','N5P','N5R','N6H','N6P','N6N','N6L','N6E','N6M','N5V','N5X','N6G','N6K','N6J','N6C','N5Z','N5W','N5Y','N6A','N6B','N7W','N7T','N7S','N7V','N7X','N0E','N4B','N3Y','N4T','N4V','N3L','N3T','N3S','N3R','N3P','N3V','N0A','N1A','L0S','L3K','L0R','N3W','L3B','L2A','L2E','L3C','L2R','L2V','L2G','L2H','L2T','L2J','L2P','L2S','L2N','L2M','L2W','L3M','L8J','L9G','L8E','L8G','L8K','L8T','L8W','L9B','L9A','L8V','L9C','L9K','L9H','N1R','L8H','L8L','L8M','L8P','L8S','L8R','L8N','L7T','L7R','L7P','N0J','N4S','N0B','N0K','N5A','N3A','N0G','N7A','N2Z','N4N','N4W','N1M','N3B','N1H','N2J','N2K','N2L','N2V','N2T','N2M','N2N','N2G','N2B','N2E','N2R','N2P','N3C','N3H','N2A','N2C','N2H','N1K','N1E','N1G','N1L','N1C','N3E','N1T','N1S','N1P','L0P','L7J','L0N','N4G','N4X','L9T','L7G','L7M','L7L','L6M','L6L','L9W','L7K','L7C','N0C','L0M','L9R','L0G','L7E','L6R','L6Z','L7A','L6P','N0H','N4K','N4L','L9Y','L9Z','L6X','L6Y','L5N','L5W','L5M','L6S','L6V','L6W','L6T','L5H','L5J','L6J','L6H','L6K','L5L','L5K','L5G','L5E','L5C','L5B','L5A','L4Y','L5V','L5R','L4Z','L4W','L4X','L5T','M8W','M9C','L4T','L5S','M9W','M9B','M8Z','M8V','M8Y','M8X','M9A','M9R','M9P','M9V','L4L','L0J','L4H','M9L','M9M','M9N','M6M','M6N','M6S','M6R','M6P','M3N','M3L','M6K','M6H','M6E','M6B','M6L','M3M','M3K','M6A','M3J','L4K','M5V','M5J','M4M','M4L','M5A','M5E','M6J','M5T','M5G','M5B','M5H','M5C','M6G','M5S','M4Y','M4X','M5R','M6C','M5P','M4V','M4W','M4T','M4K','M4J','M4G','M4S','M5N','M4R','M4P','M4N','M5M','M3H','M4H','M4C','M4E','M3C','M4B','M3B','M2L','M2P','M2N','M2R";
```

I am not sure, now how to proceed further. Please help me out.

Comment: The query string is too big with all those zip codes. You need to make the query shorter for it to work.  Can you add a column which will determine whether that postal code should be displayed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I too thought of adding a column whether the postal code will be displayed or not?